# create arrays of DOM object in matlab for multiple read xml files

Tags: matlab

I have many XML files, and get their filenames like so:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.xml','MultiSelect','on');
```

I want to read these files using this code:

```
for i=1:length(fullfile(FileName)) 
    xtree(i) = xmlread(char(fullfile(FileName(i))));
```

but I got an error. It works well for a single XML file:

```
xtree = xmlread(char(fullfile(FileName)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using cell arrays properly. Do you know what they are? Type `help cell` in Matlab to find out more.

Basically, what's going on here is that `uigetfile` outputs a cell-array of filenames called `FileName`. You access each filename by curcly-brace indexing (`{}`).

Similarly, each node is a special object that cannot be captured properly by a normal Marlab array. You're better off defining `xtree` as a cell-array as well, and assign the output of `xmlread` again with curly braces.

Also: when reading files input by the user at runtime, it is **always** better to extensively check for errors.

Summarized:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.m','MultiSelect','on');

if isequal(FileName,0) || isequal(PathName,0)
    error('Cancel pressed.');

else
    xtree = cell(size(FileName));
    for i=1:numel(FileName)
        try
            xtree{i} = xmlread(fullfile([PathName FileName{i}]));

        catch ME
            %# handle error
        end
    end

end
```