# First time working with MATLAB and XML

Tags: java, xml, matlab, dom

Like it says it's my first time working with XML and I'm having a hard time working with basic functionality in MATLAB, any suggestions are appreciated:

I've got a basic file like this:

```
<list>
<listitem>
    <label>TEST</label>
            <value>VALUE</value>
    <label>TEST_2</label>
            <value>VALUE_2</value>
    ...ETC... 
</listitem>

<listitem>
   ...
<listitem>
</list>
```

And obviously my script should run through each *listitem* collect stopping at a label, collecting its value and moving on down the list. I started using the example script that MATLAB provides for working with the DOM but I can't get it to work out beyond only the first label.

Can anyone provide help?

Thanks!

EDIT: So I *am* using `xmlread` and have searched. I also feel like this is a pretty generic question that might help others in the future.

Comment: Did you bother to search? There are many duplicate questions, such as: [extracting data from within xml files using MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706980/), [create arrays of DOM object in matlab for multiple read xml files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190539/), [How to get Matlab to read correct amount of xml nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548590/), _etc_...

Comment: Not being able to get something to work is not really a question. You need to be specific. For a simple file like the example you provide, what code are you using? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: @horchler ... I started using the example MATLAB doc code for working with XML and DOM (see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-xml-documents.html#bsmj8nj-1). I'm pretty new to working with XML so I'm getting lost fast.

Comment: Generic questions help no one. Your question [needs to be specific](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be of value to the community and for anyone here to have a clue of understanding where you are going wrong. Don't expect someone to write a treatise on XML and `xmlread` explaining it all to you. Break down your problem. Debug your code as you would any Matlab code. Don't expect to get fast results when you're "new" to something.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the builtin xmlread - it's a royal pain in the elbow. Just use http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4278-xml-toolbox